# Is there any android/iOS SDK for M-Pesa payment gateway?

Tags: android, ios, payment-gateway, mpesa

I am searching **M-Pesa** Android/iOS SDK. If have, can anyone give me this SDK and if no, can anyone please explain the procedure to implement M-Pesa payment gateway in Android/iOS?

Comment: For Which country you need?

Comment: I need M-Pesa Android SDK for  Tanzania

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry bro they are not publish any SDK yet and not publish by other yet. Please make yourself.